# How to add script & PHP code to the <head> section of a block editor theme template?

Tags: block-editor

How can I add script and PHP code to the `<head>` section of a theme template of a particular Category that utilizes the built-in block editor in WP?

Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      let map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), {
        <?php 
        $lat= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gmap-latitude', true);
        $lon= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gmap-longitude', true);
        echo 'center: {lat: '.$lat.', lng: '.$lon.'},';?>
        zoom: 14,
        });
      }
    window.initMap = initMap;
</script>
```

Some background info:

I'm trying to transition the theme of my website using old-school template files (ex., single-map.php) to the new twenty twenty-three WP theme using its built-in block editor.

And one of my website's Category ("Map") has 3.000+ pages, all of which with the above code in their `<head>` section (and another script in the `<body>`). Then, in the post editing screen of each page, I entered latitude and longitude values using Custom Fields.

Besides a solution for my initial problem, if there's a better way of doing this, I'm eager to know!

Comment: There's probably a pure code solution that I'm not aware of, but I often use the free plugin WP Code for problems like this. In the "Header and Footer" section of the plugin, enter your code in the "Header" box and save. Should show up on every page in the `<head>` section. Just tested it with the Twenty Twenty-Three theme and it works with that.

Comment: note that a map block would provide solutions for this. Likewise you don't need to use PHP to generate the `center` JSON, `data` attributes can do this already, and you can already use WP APIs to attach data to objects without having to manually print it out like that so this approach is already not ideal in a classic theme . Take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/ and also consider using `data` attributes as right now this approach makes multiple maps impossible. Similarly in non-block themes you're meant to use filters to put stuff in the head

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add script and PHP code to the  section of a theme template of a particular Category that utilizes the built-in block editor in WP?

The same way you were always supposed to in classic themes, nothing has changed!

**Use the `wp_head` action** in combination with the `is_category` action.

Note that while classic themes allowed you to modify the `head` tag directly via `header.php`, block themes don't, but doing that was never best practice to begin with.

Other notes:

- manually constructing JSON like that is dangerous! It's much easier to do `<?php echo wp_json_encode( [ 'center' => [ 'lat' => ...], 'zoom' => 14 ) ); ?>`, now the contents of those post meta can't break your JS and give you syntax errors
- that JS should be in a javascript file, not inline, I can see it was included in the header so that you could print out the post meta values, but this should have been done in `data` attributes read off of `document.getElementById("gmap")` e.g. `<div data-lat="123" data-long="456">`
- A simple block named `Ferienflieger/map-block` that printed out lat and long on a `div` using a server side rendered block could be done entirely with PHP and a `block.json` file. This would make inserting blocks easier, optimise your site by allowing WP to only add the JS when the block is used, allow multiple maps if you so wanted, eliminate the need to put anything in the header, and avoid mistakes in the site editor. You could even give it a pretty map icon that shows up in the outliner

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints, Tom! This is fairly new to me. data... wp_json_encode... block.json... I'll dig into it in order to understand the whole thing. Will get back soon. Thanks again.

Comment: building a block isn't strictly what you asked for, but, it is something you should take an interest in, there are many more options than you might be aware of, or than what I mentioned, but I don't want to sidetrack your question. You can always create new questions for new questions and get proper answers instead of short comments :)